# RabbitMq unable to login with newly created user

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I Created a new user `appserviceaccount` using the default guest administrator account and set administrator tag on that user.
I am able to login to the web interface using the newly created user, But not able to login via C# client to publish messages and consume them. Error i receive is below, I have no clues as to why this is happening.

```
2018-04-18 12:42:15.409 [info] <0.5272.2> accepting AMQP connection <0.5272.2> (127.0.0.1:65155 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2018-04-18 12:42:15.460 [info] <0.5272.2> Connection <0.5272.2> (127.0.0.1:65155 -> 127.0.0.1:5672) has a client-provided name: Application
2018-04-18 12:42:15.461 [error] <0.5272.2> Error on AMQP connection <0.5272.2> (127.0.0.1:65155 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, state: starting):
PLAIN login refused: user 'appserviceaccount' - invalid credentials
2018-04-18 12:42:15.464 [info] <0.5272.2> closing AMQP connection <0.5272.2> (127.0.0.1:65155 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - Application)
```

C# Code used to establish connection is below, i had to mask the password. Error occurs when `CreateConnection` is called.

```
var connFact = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory();
            connFact.HostName = "localhost";
            connFact.UserName = "appserviceaccount";
            connFact.Password = "XXXXXXX";
            connFact.VirtualHost = "/";
            Console.WriteLine("This is a Sender");
            try
            {
                using (var conn = connFact.CreateConnection("Application"))
                {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, **Restarting** RabbitMq service did the trick. Now any new user i am adding is able to read queues using c# client.

Comment: I doubt that the restart is actually what fixed this, to be honest. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @LukeBakken Yeah it was just crazy for me too to accept this.